# How can I compute the coefficientsof the impuse response given a signal?

Tags: discrete-signals, impulse-response

How can I compute the coefficients of the transfer function with the following difference equation:
$$y[n]=x[n]+y[n-1]-0.5y[n-2]$$

Answer (score 1):

A system can be represented by its **transfer function**:
$$H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{b_0 + b_1z^{-1} + b_2z^{-2}+ \dots +b_{M-1}z^{-(M-1)}}{a_0 + a_1z^{-1} + a_2z^{-2} +\dots+ a_{N-1}z^{-(N-1)}}$$ and its associated **difference equation**:
$$a_0y[n] = b_0x[n] + b_1x[n-1] + b_2x[n-2]+ \dots + b_{M-1}x[n-M+1]\\-a_1y[n-1]-a_2y[n-2]-\dots-a_{N-1}y[n-N+1]$$

where $b_0, b_1, b_2, \dots, b_{M-1}, a_0, a_1, a_2, \dots a_{N-1}$ are the **coefficients**.

You can "read out" the coefficients from the difference equation, or you can take the difference equation to the $\mathcal{Z}$-domain and derive the transfer function $\frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}$

---

For difference equation
$$y[n] = x[n] + y[n-1]-0.5y[n-2]$$
We have, in $\mathcal{Z}$-domain:
$$Y(z)=X(z)+z^{-1}Y(z)-0.5z^{-2}Y(z)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow Y(z) - z^{-1}Y(z)+0.5z^{-2}Y(z)  = X(z) $$
$$\Leftrightarrow Y(z)\big(1 - z^{-1}+0.5z^{-2}\big) = X(z)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow H(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} = \frac{1}{1 - z^{-1}+0.5z^{-2}}$$

So your coefficients are:
$$b_0 = 1$$
$$a_0 = 1$$
$$a_1 = -1$$
$$a_2 = 0.5$$

Comment: Note that the big step here is "We have in the $z$-domain...  This depends on several properties of the $z$ transform which are presented fairly early on in an introduction to the $z$ domain, and which, if used correctly, make this step obvious.  If you're serious about this stuff, you may want to study up.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @IagoÁlvarez if you’re satisfied with the answer, please hit the “accept answer” button so others can benefit ;)